# Is it possible to Serialize a LINQ object?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, serialization

I'd like to serialize some LINQ generated objects and store them in a table as a binary field (Never you mind why). I'd like to be able to write some code that looks something like this:

```
SerialTestDataContext db = new SerialTestDataContext();

relation_table row = db.relation_tables.First();

MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
bin.Serialize(memStream, row);
Console.WriteLine("Serilized successfully");

TestTable tt = new testTable();
tt.data = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(memStream.ToArray());
db.testTables.InsertOnSubmit(tt);
db.SubmitChanges();
Console.WriteLine("Inserted successfully");
```

Currently that fails even though I've marked the generated classes as [Serializable] because one of the LINQ inherited classes is not. Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With linq-to-sql (from tags), then yes: you can mark the dmbl as serializable, which uses the [DataContract]/[DataMember] approach. You do this by setting the "Serialization Mode" to "Unidirectional" in the designer, or you can do it in the dbml itself:

```
<Database ... Serialization="Unidirectional">...
```

You can then use DataContractSerializer or NetDataContractSerializer to write this (as xml or binary respectively). If you need something portable (i.e. not MS/.NET specific), then [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) will serialize data-contracts using the "protocol buffers" spec.

Comment: how come when i tried to do this, and try to serialize to memcached, it's not working? :|

Comment: @DucDigital - does memcached support `DataContractSerializer`? Or does it just use `BinaryFormatter`? In which case you need to add `[Serializable]`. Let me know...

Comment: You have to add Serializable in to your classes, but why i mean is that, i cannot serialize the linq objects, i even i tried with several wraper to make sure if i can save to Memcached. I tried to change to Unidirectional but no helps, you can check out my examples in this opening question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122081/is-there-anyway-to-serilize-linq-object-for-memcached . hope we can solve this since there really no documents about this

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using an entity which has properties of type `EntitySet<T>` when serializing by using `NetDataContractSerializer` :(

Comment: Thanks a lot!! you are the best!

Answer (score 6):

Following Marc Gravell's advice I wrote the following two blocks of code which worked beautifully:

```
relation_table row = db.relation_tables.First();

MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
NetDataContractSerializer ndcs = new NetDataContractSerializer();
ndcs.Serialize(memStream, row);

byte[] stuff = memStream.toArray();

memStream = new MemoryStream(stuff);
row = ndcs.Deserialize(memStream);

db.relation_tables.Attach(row);
Console.WriteLine(row.data_table1.somedata + ": " + row.more_data);
```

The Attach() call fills in the foreign key dependencies for me and associates the item with the data context.

Answer (score 5):

MSDN: [Serialization (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546184.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Linq classes are partial classes.  You can change the definition to mark the classes as implementing [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) and then provide the code...

```
public partial class User : ISerializable
{
  // implement GetObjectData here
}
```

There might still be issues with deserialization, however (I'm not 100% on this).  An alternative is to use xml serialization and implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx), which has methods for serializing and deserializing, allowing you to control the entire process...