# Is there anyway to serilize linq object for Memcached?

Tags: linq-to-sql, memcached

I'm just start switching to memcached and currently on testing with memcached.

I'm having 2 object, I created an object and put [Serializable] on it (for instance, let call this `Object1`), the other object is created using Linq DBML (`Object2`)..

I tried to memcached `List<Object1>`, it work just fine, like charm, everything here is cache and loaded properly.

But then, i move on to the Linq object, now i try to add to memcached `List<Object2>` this does not work, it did not add to memcached at all. no key was added

I move on and change the Serialization Mode to Unidirectional,  do the add again, still no hope.

Is there anyway to make this work?

Here is the simple test I just wrote, using MemcachedProvider from codeplex to demonstrate:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var returnObj = DistCache.Get<List<Post>>("testKey");
    if (returnObj == null)
    {
        DataContext _db = new DataContext();
        returnObj = _db.Posts.ToList();
        DistCache.Add("testKey", returnObj, new TimeSpan(29, 0, 0, 0));
        _db.Dispose();
    }

    return Content(returnObj.First().TITLE);
}
```

this is from Memcached, no STORE was called:

```
> NOT FOUND _x_testKey
>532 END
<528 get _x_testKey
> NOT FOUND _x_testKey
>528 END
<516 get _x_testKey
> NOT FOUND _x_testKey
>516 END
```

And in my SQL profiler, it called 3 query for 3 test time => Proved that the object called back from Memcached is null, then it query.

Comment: This question could benefit from (1) Some code samples (2) Clearer explanation of what is going wrong exactly and (3) How exactly you're using memcached from .NET.  There are multiple .NET wrappers and they may not all behave the same in this regard.

Comment: I added all you need. The wraper im using is MemcachedProvider from codeplex. The object1 was successfully added but somehow the linq object did not.

Comment: The extra info helps, but I don't see a problem.  Have you debugged the Add() call?  What about using a TCP proxy or Wireshark to see if MemcachedProvider is even sending anything to memcached for this request?

Comment: The add call do is just a call to Erym(or something) wraper for memcached. I see no problem with this in the source file. I will try to get another wraper and see if it's because of MemCachedProvider problem. But in the mean time if anyone know anything or experience anything pls help me out. My idea is to find a way to add Serialize to linq objects

Comment: For info, I wrote a protobuf-net wrapper for this scenario; you could use this "as is", or you could write something very similar and use DataContractSerializer. Blog: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/01/distributed-caching-with-protobuf-net.html, Code: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net.Extensions/Caching/Enyim/ProtoTranscoder.cs

Comment: yes, i checked out your repo. I will check on my Model soon. :) Btw, this is exactly what i think of the use of protobuf. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the default implementation (`DefaultTranscoder`) is to use `BinaryFormatter`; the "unidirectional" stuff is an instruction to a different serializer (`DataContractSerializer`), and **doesn't** add `[Serializable]`.

(Note: I've added a [memo to myself](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=89) to try to write a protobuf-net transcoder for memcached; that would be *cool* and would fix most of this for free)

I haven't tested, but a few options present themselves:

1. write a different transcoder implementation that detects `[DataContract]` and uses `DataContractSerializer`, and hook this transcoder
2. add `[Serializable]` to your types via a partial class (I'm not convinced this will work due to the LINQ field types not being serializable)
3. add an `ISerializable` implementation in a partial class that uses `DataContractSerializer`
4. like 3, but using protobuf-net, which a: works with "unidirectional", and b: is faster and smaller than `DataContractSerializer`
5. write a serializable DTO and map your types to *that*

The last is simple but may add more work.

I'd be tempted to to look at the 3rd option first, as the 1st involves rebuilding the provider; the 4th option would also *definitely* be on my list of things to test.

---

I struggled with 3, due to the DCS returning a *different* object during deserialization; I switched to protobuf-net instead, so here's a version that shows adding a `partial class` to your existing `[DataContract]` type that makes it work with `BinaryFormatter`. Actually, I suspect (with evidence) this will also make it much efficient (than raw `[Serializable]`), too:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using ProtoBuf;

/* DBML generated */
namespace My.Object.Model
{
    [DataContract]
    public partial class MyType
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
/* Your extra class file */
namespace My.Object.Model
{
    // this adds **extra** code into the existing MyType
    [Serializable]   
    public partial class MyType : ISerializable {
        public MyType() {}
        void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
            Serializer.Serialize(info, this);
        }
        protected MyType(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
            Serializer.Merge(info, this);
        }
    }
}
/* quick test via BinaryFormatter */
namespace My.App
{
    using My.Object.Model;
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MyType obj = new MyType { Id = 123, Name = "abc" }, clone;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
                ms.Position = 0;
                clone = (MyType)bf.Deserialize(ms);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(clone.Id);
            Console.WriteLine(clone.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i added some comment on your issue, can you check out?