# What do you recommend for distributed cache linq to sql object?

Tags: linq-to-sql, memcached

[Is there anyway to serilize linq object for Memcached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122081/is-there-anyway-to-serilize-linq-object-for-memcached)
I asked a question previously here, but really no one help out on this. I was wondering is there anyway to cache linq to sql object... like List or something similar, where there are hierachy...

I tried most Wraper for memcached and it does not work. So I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [sharedcache.com](http://www.sharedcache.com)

Comment: Hi DucDigital, you've accepted this answer but not upvoted. I'm in a similar position and wondered if this solved your issue?