# LINQ Entity Serialization with Memcached

Tags: linq-to-sql, memcached

I'm working on integrating Memcached (using the Enyim Memcached library for .NET) in my application and would like to cache data at every layer (data, business, app).  I'm using LINQ to SQL for the data access layer.  In trying to cache LINQ entites I ran into a problem in that Enyim uses the Binary formatter for serialization, which is the wrong serializer for LINQ objects (should be DataContractSerializer).

Anyone have experience with this scenario that can offer suggestions?  Any advice is insight or advice is most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find this answer helpful... in my case I went the ProtoBuf route and it works great: [Is there anyway to serilize linq object for Memcached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122081/is-there-anyway-to-serilize-linq-object-for-memcached)